# Need to filter data rows where the data is past a certain month

Tags: python, pandas

Need to look at rows where the date columns is April only. However my data is in YYYY-MM-DD

How can I write a conditional to ensure month = 4 (April.)

Comment: Did you realize that all answers up to now start with "Assuming..."? Please, save us all the time to _guess_ what you _perhaps might mean_... Consider editing your question according to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming date in string format is stored in `date_str` column, and `df` is the Pandas dataframe.

```py
# Convert string date to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_str'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Select rows for April
df.loc[df['date'].dt.month == 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is your starting point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.random.rand(13),
    "date": pd.date_range("2019-03-01", "2019-05-31", freq="W")
})

#            x       date
# 0   0.493852 2019-03-03
# 1   0.335280 2019-03-10
# 2   0.892476 2019-03-17
# 3   0.612119 2019-03-24
# 4   0.446722 2019-03-31
# 5   0.236843 2019-04-07
# 6   0.413819 2019-04-14
# 7   0.228923 2019-04-21
# 8   0.401895 2019-04-28
# 9   0.183924 2019-05-05
# 10  0.457840 2019-05-12
# 11  0.490073 2019-05-19
# 12  0.224978 2019-05-26
```

...you can simply do:

```
df.date.dt.month == 4

# 0     False
# 1     False
# 2     False
# 3     False
# 4     False
# 5      True
# 6      True
# 7      True
# 8      True
# 9     False
# 10    False
# 11    False
# 12    False
# Name: date, dtype: bool
```